# Mapstruct Plugin IDEA Support

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mapstruct

I a using IDEA Ultimate 2019.2. After installing Mapstruct plugin 1.2.1 or any other I am getting the folowing issue after restart:

[image]

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapstruct/Mapper
    at org.mapstruct.intellij.util.MapstructUtil.<clinit>(MapstructUtil.java:70)
    at org.mapstruct.intellij.inspection.WrongUsageOfMappersFactoryInspection.<clinit>(WrongUsageOfMappersFactoryInspection.java:42)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.AbstractExtensionPointBean.findClass(AbstractExtensionPointBean.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.AbstractExtensionPointBean.findClass(AbstractExtensionPointBean.java:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.AbstractExtensionPointBean.instantiate(AbstractExtensionPointBean.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEP.instantiateTool(InspectionEP.java:195)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolWrapper.getTool(InspectionToolWrapper.java:71)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolWrapper.getGroupPath(InspectionToolWrapper.java:152)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.processOptions(InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader.preload(SearchableOptionPreloader.java:32)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$1(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$componentsInitialized$2(Preloader.java:71)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.lambda$run$0(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapstruct.Mapper PluginClassLoader[org.mapstruct.intellij, 1.2.1] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@121be36c
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Why not using a up-to-date version of IDEA ? 2020.X ?

Comment: It's company provided.

Comment: I would continue to do as described in the plugin ....

Comment: This is really weird. We have ~15k users using the plugin and we haven't seen this problem. How did you install the plugin?

Comment: I had downloaded it from the plugin website and uploaded to IDEA